# apache shiro url matching with apache tapestry

Tags: shiro, tapestry

So here is my configuration

```
configuration.add(factory.createChain("/abc/*")
            .add(factory.anon()).build());
    configuration.add(factory.createChain("/pdf/pdfReport/*")
            .add(factory.authc()).build());
    configuration.add(factory.createChain("/*").add(factory.authc())
            .build());
```

The problem i am facing is /abc is in root path and if i make it anonymous then shiro still redirects it to login page.

I guess /* is overwriting the /abc request and send every root reqyest for authentication because if i comment this code

```
configuration.add(factory.createChain("/*").add(factory.authc())
            .build());
```

then i can access /abc anonymously.Can anyone please guide how can i keep both and still achieve mu functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.I just need to give

```
configuration.add(factory.createChain("/abc")
        .add(factory.anon()).build());
```

instead of /* because /* is alreadu authenticated for every url after / in the chain